# Unterschied zwischen "Ich habe mir sagen lassen" und "Mir wurde gesagt"

Tags: phrase

Einer unserer Professoren an der Hochschule sagte oft

> Ich habe mir sagen lassen, dass...

wenn er etwas erzählte. Meine Frage ist: Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen dieser Aussage und

> Mir wurde gesagt, dass...

Möchte man im ersten Fall zum Ausdruck bringen, dass man an der Richtigkeit des Inhaltes der Aussage zweifelt oder sogar an der Kompetenz desjenigen, der es gesagt hat?

Comment: Der Zweifel ist m.E. eher im zweiten Fall möglich (aber nicht notwendig), siehe meine Antwort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Den ersten Ausdruck hört man häufig, wenn der Sprecher klarstellen will (oder so tun, als ob), dass er eine Information nicht aus sich heraus weiß, um z. B. nicht als Klugscheißer dazustehen.

> Der Schmelzpunkt von Aluminium liegt bei 660,32 Grad, habe ich mir
>   sagen lassen.

Der zweite Ausdruck wird gern genutzt, wenn von einer übergeordneten Person oder Stelle die Rede ist.

> »Mir wurde gesagt, dass unsere Abteilung zum 1.7. aufgelöst wird.«
>
> »Du gießt Unkraut? Ist das dein Ernst?«
>   »Mir wurde gesagt, dass ich das heute machen soll.«

Im letzten Beispiel mag der Sprecher durchaus Zweifel an Richtigkeit oder Kompetenz dessen anmelden, auf den er verweist, denn seine Antwort klingt wie eine Rechtfertigung.

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese Antwort! Ich denke, das wird genau der Fall gewesen sein, dass der Prof nicht als Klugscheißer da stehen wollte. Die Intonation, mit der er es immer gesagt hat und die Tatsache, dass es meistens sehr fachspezifische Themen betraf deuten darauf hin :)

Comment: Ich dachte, es sei eine Berufskrankheit von Professoren, Klugscheißer *zu sein* ;)

Answer (score 3):

> Ich habe mir sagen lassen, dass ...

bedeutet dasselbe wie "ich habe erfahren, dass ...". Es ist mir also irgendwie zur Kenntnis gekommen (und man hat es nicht einmal notwendigerweise gesagt).

> Mir wurde gesagt, dass ...

Bedeutet genau das - Jemand hat es mir gesagt.

Einen Unterschied am vermuteten Wahrheitsgehalt kann ich nicht ausmachen.

Was bisweilen vorkommt, ist, dass "sich sagen lassen" im Zusammenhang mit "müssen" auch bedeuten kann, dass man belehrt oder ermahnt wurde:

> ... da musste ich mir sagen lassen, dass man in der Strassenbahn nicht pupsen soll.

Comment: Vielen Dank auch für diese Erklärung!

Answer (score 2):

*Ich habe mir sagen lassen* deutet zumindest an, dass die Initiative von mir ausging, also ich jemanden gefragt habe. *Mir wurde gesagt* schließt das zwar nicht aus, würde aber auch den Fall umfassen, in dem die Information völlig unfreiwillig erfolgt ist.

Alternative: das *sagen lassen* bedeutet soviel wie *gelten lassen*, *stehen lassen* oder *unwidersprochen hinnehmen*.

Comment: Danke für diese Antwort!

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt da keinen großen Unterschied.

Aber, meiner Meinung nach, klingt:

> Ich habe mir sagen lassen

ein wenig apologetisch, also wie:

> Man hat es mir gesagt (vielleicht: nachdem ich gefragt habe) und ich glaube es

während, meiner Meinung nach, der Ausdruck:

> Mir wurde gesagt

freibleibender ist, also nicht angibt, ob derjenige das Gesagte auch glaubt.

Aber es ist gut möglich, dass das nur mein persönliches Empfinden ist, und es da gar keinen Unterschied gibt. Groß ist er immerhin nicht.

Comment: Danke auch für diese Antwort! Habe erst mal googeln müssen, was "apologetisch" bedeutet ;)